# Deixar apenas letras e numeros de um cookie

Tags: php

Tenho um cookie que me retorna

> ct0=945d9ead4b3ce88d5aba8f09a4d78aee;

Usando o `explode` consegui deixa-lo assim:

> '945d9ead4b3ce88d5aba8f09a4d78aee; '

Repare que tem um `;`, ponto e espaço no final, quero deixar apenas caracteres não especiais.

Eis aqui o meu codigo:

```
$ct0 = explode('ct0=', $cookie[4]);
```

Acho que resolvi com este código:

```
$ct0 = explode('ct0=', $cookie[4]);
$ct0 = explode('; ', $ct0[1]);
```

Se tiver outra maneira de fazer isso sou grato.

### EDITADO

```
<?php

class Login {

    private $_url;
    private $_cookieFile;

    public $_username = '';
    public $_password = '';

    public function __construct($url) {
        $this->_url = $url;
    }

    public function setCookieFile($cookieFile) {
        $this->_cookieFile = $cookieFile;
    }

    public function setUsername($username) {
        $this->_username = $username;
    }

    public function setPassword($password) {
        $this->_password = $password;
    }

    public function login($username, $password) {
        $request = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($request, [
                CURLOPT_URL                         => $this->_url,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       => 'GET',
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
                CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
                CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR               => $this->_cookieFile,
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT               => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
                CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION  => function($curl, $header) use (&$cookie) {
                    if (stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0) {
                        if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: \s*([^;]*)/i', $header, $matches)) {
                            $cookie[] = $matches[1] . '; ';
                        }
                    }
                    return strlen($header);
                },
                CURLOPT_COOKIE                  => $cookie,
            ]
        );
        $response = curl_exec($request);

        preg_match('/value="(.*?)" name="authenticity_token"/', $response, $matches);

        $authenticity_token = $matches[1];

        $post_fields = http_build_query([
            'session' => [
                'username_or_email' => $username,
                'password'                  => $password
            ],
                'return_to_ssl'                 => true,
                'scribe_log'                        => '',
                'redirect_after_login'  => '/',
                'authenticity_token'        => $authenticity_token
            ]
        );

        curl_setopt_array($request, [
                CURLOPT_URL                         => $this->_url . '/sessions',
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       => 'POST',
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS          => $post_fields,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
                CURLOPT_HEADER                  => false,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
                CURLOPT_COOKIE                  => $cookie[0] . $cookie[1] . $cookie[2] . $cookie[3] . $cookie[4],
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT               => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER          => [
                    'accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
                    'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'origin: https://twitter.com',
                    'referer: https://twitter.com/login',
                ],
            ]
        );

        $response = curl_exec($request);
        curl_close($request);

        $ct0 = explode('ct0=', $cookie[4]);
        $ct0 = explode('; ', $ct0[1]);

        if ($response === '') {
            Session::set('ct0', $ct0);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Retornei esse cookie do twitter.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, com a solução,

Comment: Pronto eu editei postei o código, está funcionando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
$cookie = 'ct0=945d9ead4b3ce88d5aba8f09a4d78aee;';

$ct0 = explode('ct0=', $cookie);

$ct0 = trim($ct0[1]); //Limpa qualquer espaçamento
$ct0 = trim($ct0, ';'); //Remove o `;`
```

Ou mais garantido se usar `preg_match` (o `preg_quote` é pra escapar os caracteres que podem interferir na *regex*), o *match* da regex pode ser assim:

```
chave=([\s\S]+?)(;|$)
```

O `([\s\S]+?)` irá pegar qualquer coisa até encontrar o ponto e virgula e o `(;|$)` irá fazer checar se é o final da string ou se é tem outros cookies, deve ficar assim:

```
function getCookie($key, $cookie) {
    if (preg_match('#' . preg_quote($key) . '=([\s\S]+?)(;|$)#i', $cookie, $output)) {
        return $output[1];
    }
}

$cookie = 'ct0=945d9ead4b3ce88d5aba8f09a4d78aee;foobar=945d9ead4b3ce88d5ab&a8f09a4d78aee';

var_dump(getCookie('ct0', $cookie));
var_dump(getCookie('foobar', $cookie));
```

Exemplo no IDEONE: https://ideone.com/ykoBfH

Comment: Ta mas a minha solução não é mais simples? `$ct0 = explode('ct0=', $cookie[4]);
  $ct0 = explode('; ', $ct0[1]);`

Comment: Ta bom vou faze-lo desta forma do seu post grato, alias ja copiei e fiz. rsrs

Comment: Ia dar +1 mas não tenho rap, uma pergunta, básica: o CT0 do twitter não contem caracteres especiais apenas letras e numeros, era os cookies que estavao me retornando `'ct0=numeros&letras; '`

Comment: Agora tá lindo, porém não é todos os cookies que vou precisar, mas tenho outro site que precisa disso. Vc já adiantou o outro lado meu, obrigado.